Why did only two of the angels go inside Sodom and Gomorrah?
Why were there three angels that went to the gate of Sodom and Gomorrah but only 2 went inside? We know that two went in but I really want to know why the third angel wasn't allowed inside the gate to Sodom & Gomorrah.

Welcome to Stack Exchange. Only two actual angels went to Sodom and Gomorrah according to Genesis 19:1, "Now the two angels came to Sodom in the evening as Lot was sitting in the gate of Sodom." It says at Genesis 18:1, "Now the Lord appeared to him/Abraham by the oaks of Mamre, while he was sitting at the tent door in the heat of the day." Vs2 states, "behold three men were standing opposite him:" One of the men was the "angle of the Lord" who is the preincarnate Jesus Christ and is identified as the Lord God. Please read the rest of Genesis 18. Also read all of Genesis 17, note verses 1-5.

this question provides answers that may help, but it is not exactly a duplicate so I will not suggest closing it.

BTW Kylie. You should provide the relevant bible verses for you question, either in the headline by citing chapter and verse or by quoting them in full in the text. I would edit the question for you but one of the moderators asked me not to do this.  The verses are in Gen 18-19

An interesting study is why there are always 2 angels.
2 angels cover the throne of God.
2 angels accompany Jesus when he visits Abraham's tent. Abraham recognizing his voice as the Lord.
2 cherubim in the sanctuary 1 Kings 6:23.
2 cherubim in the Holy of holies 2 Chronicles 3:10.
2 angels standing beside the disciples as Jesus ascended to heaven Acts 1:10. 2 angels at the tomb in John 20:12.
2 angels assist the Jews as they leave Babylon to come back into Israel.
According to Genesis 19:24, the 2 angels went in to Lot's house to escort him to safety. Meanwhile, the 3rd (The Lord) called down destruction.
Gen 19:24 -  Then the Lord rained brimstone and fire on Sodom and Gomorrah, from the Lord out of the heavens.
This is old Jewish theology called "the 2 powers in heaven", or "the 2 YHWYs"
Lord #1 on the earth rained brimstone and fire on Sodom and Gomorrah, while Lord #2 sent the brimstone and fire from out of the heavens.
Since this Lord #1 came in the form of a man to Abram's tent, ate and drank with him and Abram recognized the voice as The Lord's, it should be obvious who exactly this man is. The pre-incarnate son of God, that the prophets kept seeing and describing as, "I see God, and he looks like a son of a man". The same man who wrestled with Jacob.
So it is not that the 3rd was not allowed inside, but that he was going to call down fire from afar.

First a possible correction. The text says that three angels (actually "men") visited Abraham. Abraham sends them on their way to Sodom but he stays behind with "the Lord."  So if one of the men was actually the angel of the Lord, perhaps only two kept going to the gate of Sodom.
Now, here are some answers. The first is from a Christian perspective, the others from a Jewish one, although some Christians may affirm them as well.
@Mr. Bond gives a Christian answer in his comment in the OP: The three consisted of two normal angels plus the angel of the LORD, who is actually Jesus. When the angels departed to Sodom this angel remained with Abraham.

So the men turned from there and went toward Sodom, but Abraham still
stood before the Lord. (18:22)

The above answer also works from a Jewish perspective, if the angel of the Lord is thought of as a being who is not Jesus. Another Jewish answer is given by the 12th c. sage Rashi as quoted below:

One to destroy Sodom, the other to rescue Lot... whilst the third,
who had come to make the announcement to Sarah (concerning Isaac), had
departed as soon as he had carried out his mission (Midrash Tanchuma,
Vayera 8).

Finally, here is an answer from the viewpoint of source criticism, based on the fact that chapter 18 uses the word YHWH (the Lord) while chapter 19:22 uses the word Elohim (God). This analysis explains that a later editor wove two or more accounts together. In one of them there are three "men" and in the other, there are two "angels." So the answer to the OP's question would be that these were originally separate stories, one dealing with the visitation to Abraham, the other detailing the destruction of Sodom. In the first there are three men; in the second there are two angels.
